# how can i show the information of the oldest user in a loop?

Tags: java

I have written a program that allows the user to enter the number of patients at hand. The program then starts a loop that asks the name and age of each patient, and displays patients' average age. The only problem is I don't know how to show the information of the youngest and oldest patients at the end of the program. Here is code, can anyone help me with this please?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i, i4, a;
    String s1, s2, s3, s4;

    s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter The Number Of Patients");
    i = Integer.parseInt(s1);
    a = 0;
    long totalAges = 0;
    while (a < i) {
        s2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter patient's ID");

        s3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter patient's Name");

        s4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter patient's Age");
        i4 = Integer.parseInt(s4);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " ID : " + s2 + "\n Name : " + s3 + "\n Age : " + i4);

        totalAges += i4;
        a++;
    }

    double avgAge = ((double) totalAges) / i;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Average Age: " + avgAge);
}
```

Comment: you could just keep track of the highest and lowest value in your loop and allways compare it to your current patient that you did enter.

Answer (score 0):

You can create variables outside the loop to handle this, These variable handle the oldest and youngest person name and age as well, to compare it with current newly entered:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int i, i2, i4, a;
String s1, s2, s3, s4;
int youngestAge, oldestAge;
String youngestName = ""; 
String oldestName = "";



s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter The Number Of Patients");
i = Integer.parseInt(s1);
a = 0;
long totalAges = 0;
while (a < i) {
    s2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter patient's ID");
    i2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
    s3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter patient's Name");

    s4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter patient's Age");
    i4 = Integer.parseInt(s4);

    if(i4 < youngestAge){
      youngestAge = i4;
      youngestName = s3;
    } else if(i4 > oldestAge){
      oldestAge = i4;
      oldestName = s3;
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " ID : " + i2 + "\n Name : " + s3 + "\n Age : " + i4);

    totalAges += i4;
    a++;
}

double avgAge = ((double) totalAges) / i;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Average Age: " + avgAge);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of your youngest and oldest patient in the loop:

```
int youngest = 200;
int oldest = 0;
while (a < i) {
    s2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter patient's ID");
    i2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
    s3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter patient's Name");

    s4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter patient's Age");
    i4 = Integer.parseInt(s4);

    if (i4 < youngest) {
        youngest = i4;
    }

    if (i4 > oldest) {
        oldest = i4;
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " ID : " + i2 + "\n Name : " + s3 + "\n Age : " + i4);

    totalAges += i4;
    a++;
}
```

If you want to retrieve the whole patient data, you have to create a class patient with properties Name, ID and age and keep track of their IDs in the loop (assuming ID is unique)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep track of all info about the youngest and the oldest patients, consider creating a `Patient` class (in this example, Patient is a local class inside the main method, but you could put it out if you need )

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        class Patient{

            private int id;
            private int age;
            private String name;

        }

        int i, i2, i4, a;
        String s1, s2, s3, s4;

        s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter The Number Of Patients");
        i = Integer.parseInt(s1);
        a = 0;
        long totalAges = 0;

        Patient youngerPatient=null;
        Patient olderPatient=null;

        while (a < i) {

            Patient patient = new Patient();

            s2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter patient's ID");
            i2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
            s3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter patient's Name");

            s4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter patient's Age");
            i4 = Integer.parseInt(s4);

            patient.id=i2;
            patient.name=s3;
            patient.age=i4;

            if(youngerPatient==null || youngerPatient.age > patient.age)
                youngerPatient = patient;

            if(olderPatient==null || olderPatient.age < patient.age)
                olderPatient = patient;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " ID : " + i2 + "\n Name : " + s3 + "\n Age : " + i4);

            totalAges += i4;
            a++;
        }

        double avgAge = ((double) totalAges) / i;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Average Age: " + avgAge+ " Younger patient:" +youngerPatient.name+ " Older patient:" +olderPatient.name);

}
```

Also , if you want to keep track of all patients, you may use an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two additional integers to keep track of the youngest age and oldest age.  Assign Integer.MAX_VALUE to the youngest age and Integer.MIN_VALUE to the oldest age.  (Those are constants and are considered by many to be a better programming style than putting an otherwise arbitrary number.)  You then check to see if each entered age is a new oldest age or new youngest age, and replace the appropriate variable if so.

Here's a complete working program:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Patients
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int i, i4, a;
    String s1, s2, s3, s4;

    s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter The Number Of Patients");
    i = Integer.parseInt(s1);
    a = 0;
    long totalAges = 0;
    int youngestAge = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int oldestAge = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    while (a < i)
    {
      s2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter patient's ID");

      s3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter patient's Name");

      s4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter patient's Age");
      i4 = Integer.parseInt(s4);

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " ID : " + s2 + "\n Name : " + s3 + "\n Age : " + i4);

      if (i4 > oldestAge)
        oldestAge = i4;
      if (i4 < youngestAge)
        youngestAge = i4;

      totalAges += i4;
      a++;
    }
    double avgAge = ((double) totalAges) / i;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Average Age: " + avgAge +
        "\nYoungest age: " + youngestAge + "\nOldest age: " + oldestAge);
  }
}
```